# Unable to connect to server (over a remote connection)

Tags: c++, winsock

I have been working on this project for a while and wanted to test some new features over a remote connection, but the client failed to connect (while it was able to connect in the past). Everything works fine locally. At the moment I am not able to port foward so I'm using hamachi. I have tried capturing the hamachi network traffic with wireshark, and the client requests do arrive, but the server doesn't receive them.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Code** (error checking left out to make the code more readable):

Client:

```
   addrinfo ADDRESSINFO, *CLIENTINFO=NULL;

   ZeroMemory(&ADDRESSINFO, sizeof(ADDRESSINFO));
   ADDRESSINFO.ai_family = AF_INET;
   ADDRESSINFO.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
   ADDRESSINFO.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

   ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

   getaddrinfo(strIP.c_str(), strPort.c_str(), &ADDRESSINFO, &CLIENTINFO);

   connect(ConnectSocket, CLIENTINFO->ai_addr, CLIENTINFO->ai_addrlen);

   freeaddrinfo(CLIENTINFO);
```

Server:

```
addrinfo ADDRESSINFO, *SERVERINFO=NULL;

ZeroMemory(&ADDRESSINFO, sizeof(ADDRESSINFO));

ADDRESSINFO.ai_family = AF_INET;
ADDRESSINFO.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
ADDRESSINFO.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

getaddrinfo(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT, &ADDRESSINFO, &SERVERINFO);

ListenSocket = socket(SERVERINFO->ai_family, SERVERINFO->ai_socktype, SERVERINFO->ai_protocol);
ConnectionSocket = socket(SERVERINFO->ai_family, SERVERINFO->ai_socktype, SERVERINFO->ai_protocol);

bind(ListenSocket, SERVERINFO->ai_addr, SERVERINFO->ai_addrlen);

freeaddrinfo(SERVERINFO);

listen( ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN )

while(true)
{
    if(ConnectionSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL))
    {
                  //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Q: The first thing to check is your firewall(s): Windows firewall (on your PC), your organization's router (if applicable) and on the destination host.  It sounds like you've already done much of this.

Comment: Did that already, both hamachi and my server are allowed through.

Comment: Doesn't your 'error handling' code that you've omitted to 'improve' readability show anything? BTW what does that really mean 'the client requests do arrive, but the server doesn't receive them.' - so does server receive what client sends or not - please clarify.

Comment: Q: How much troubleshooting flexibility do you have at the server side?  Can you install Wireshark there?  Can you check the server-side firewall?

Comment: @Artur no, just WSAcleanup() and error messages (which are not displayed; there is no error). Wireshark shows them but the server doesn't accept() them. So I thought there may something wrong with the port the server is listening on, but I haven't been able to confirm this.

Comment: @paulsm4 firewall is good, wireshark is installed **server** side, and the messages show up there, the server just doesn't get them, that's the weird part.

Comment: @BioCycle: is the server Linux based?

Comment: @Artur Winsock usually isn't linux based ;P

Comment: @BioCycle: right :-D - doing too many things at once - sorry

Comment: Everything still smells like a (server-side) firewall.  Look here: http://superuser.com/questions/101525/wireshark-and-windows-firewall

Comment: @BioCycle: got it working yet?  What was the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how abridged the code that you've pasted is but:

```
1) There is no place where you set destination address
2) There is no place you set destination port
3) To which port is server trying to bind?
```

...so this just cannot work at all.
Moreover please do handle errors - (yes you said you've omitted them on purpose) but I bet that if server refuses connection your error handling shows that. Otherwise it connects fine but you claim otherwise. You also say:

```
1) 'the client failed to connect'
2) and later you say 'the client requests do arrive, but the server doesn't receive them'
```

If you are able to connect - you should see 3 way handshake (TCP stream connection). If not error handling and wireshark will show that. You say that client requests do arrive but your code is not sending anything (no sending code available). You also say that server does not receive them - if it connects and you send anything there is no way that your error handling shows nothing and server receives nothing (but server code lacks any receive routine call).

I think right now you cannot receive much help with that. Update your code, verify if it really works locally (you mean loopback here right?), then test 'not locally', add error handling and use wireshark on both client and server side.

Comment: BTW Artur: I agree with everything you say.  The code (as posted) cannot possibly work.  But based on everything BioCycle says, I believe his actual program *is* working.  A firewall can cause *exactly* the symptoms above: 1) Wireshark trace on the server shows SYN attempt(s) from the client, but 2) the server does not respond, and 3) consequently, the "connect" fails.  As you requested, it's essential that he verify both client and server work locally.

Comment: I found out hamachi is causing the problems, I tried it over LAN and that worked fine. So I'll dump hamachi and go for port forwarding, because hamachi isn't working at all. I still don't think it is a firewall related issue, because hamachi is allowed through. Thanks anyway.

Comment: (And, as said before, no errors showed up. Therefore I decided it was irrelevant to add them to this code (they are there in the actual program!!))